# How i update status of facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How I can update status for my facebook page from other site from javascript.Please tell me how i can do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you google and put some effort before asking it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should greatly help you

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts